# nservicebus multiple endpoint configuration

Tags: nservicebus

Is there any way to configure 2 endpoints with different transport in NServiceBus to receive messages from one endpoint and publish an event to another endpoint?

I am looking for a solution to configure ASP.Net Core web API application which takes messages from DataBus (NServiceBus with MongoDB transport) and after processing messages, publish an event to another Bus (in my case EventBus, NServiceBus with rabbitmq transport).

Comment: Could you specify what it is you're trying to achieve? Why are you using two different transports (aka queuing technologies)? Why are you calling them DataBus and EventBus?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a [bridge or router](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/router/) to do that, but I'd recommend using a single bus for your system.